# Multi-Monitor Taskbars with UltraMon: showing the Start Button and the Tray Icons

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, ultramon

I use [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) to duplicate the taskbar across several monitors. Is there any way to show the Start Button and the Tray Icons on each taskbar like we can do with [DisplayFusion Taskbars](http://www.displayfusion.com/features/taskbar/)?

I use UltraMon 3.2.2 x64 with Windows 7.

Comment: Short answer: Nope.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks, feel free to add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to show the Start Button and the Tray Icons on each taskbar with UltraMon.